# Should I use <keypress> or <keyrelease> (or <Return>) for RFID scanning?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Raspberry Pi and an RFID scanner running a python script.  I'm using tkinter to capture input using the following code.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

def __init__(self):
    command = tk.Tk()
    self.e = Entry(command)
    self.e.grid()
    self.e.focus_set()
    command.bind('<KeyPress>', self.key_input)
    command.mainloop()

def key_input(self, event):
    key_press = event.keysym
    if key_press == 'Return':
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.enter()
    else:
        pass

def enter(self):
    //various API calls etc.  Here is where the RFID tag is often duplicated)
```

I'm getting some weird behaviour where the RFID tag is captured twice before a return is fired and I'm wondering if it is because of the order of operations.

Would binding using < keypress> vs < keyrelease> change anything?  Or not because it's an RFID scanning and not a user pressing keys?  Would using the < Return> be preferential?  Or is the above code accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Please update your question with some usable code. Just looking at your code I can see you have imported tkinter with at least 2 different methods. This should be avoided. 2nd problem I see is your key_input method is outside of the tkinter mainloop. I am guessing you are taking some small section of a class and just throwing it into this example but that wont help much with testing code. Honestly not 100% what your problem is. Your RFID scanning is going to send you a signal of some kind so just use that when you check for an event.

Comment: Why are you binding your event to your Tk object and not to the Entry object?

Comment: Can you use a print statement to detect what kind of keypress event is being triggered by your scanner? Then just use that event name going forward.

Comment: @DaveMaheux I'm new to python and tkinter, how should it be set up?  The code works most of the time, just the odd time where it fails and I thought this might be the spot.

Comment: @Craig.Pearce If your code works most of the time but sometimes fails then you should keep a running log of the event being passed and then review that log when it fails

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you press and hold the key, OS generates multiple Press and Release events in a loop, not a single Press and single Release when the key is actually finally released. So, using only one of Press or Release events won't change anything.

One possibility is it to process both Press and Release events, and track the state of the key (if key is "being pressed") in event handlers. Now, this solves nothing as is, but then the trick is to also use [`after_idle`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/after+idle) to defer the processing of the Release event. `after_idle` schedules the execution on the next event loop, and after other events are processed, so:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.being_pressed = False
    command.bind('<KeyPress-Return>', key_input)
    command.bind('<KeyRelease-Return>', key_release)

def key_input(self, event):
    if not self.being_pressed:
        self.enter()

def key_release(self, event):
    self.being_pressed = True
    self.after_idle(self.do_release, event)

def do_release(self.event):
    self.being_pressed = False
```

This way, you still get all Press and Release events, but because Release events are now processed in next event loop, if key is being pressed for a long time, `N+1` Press event handler will be executed before the `N`-th Release event handler, and thus will detect that the key is still being pressed.

Optionally, you can also use [`after cancel`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/after+cancel) in Press event handler to cancel Release event processing at all.